# Convert eBay listing to PDF file with images included

Tags: pdf, images, website, javascript

I've been trying to save some eBay listings as PDF files. I've tried sites like pdfmyurl and joliprint, and I've tried Acrobat X Pro. The problem I have with all of them is that they don't save the attached item images when there are more than one image. This has something to do with this part of the eBay page being programmed in javascript. Could someone help me with this problem? Here is an example URL that you can try it on. http://www.ebay.com/itm/Car-Window-Windshield-Vacuum-Suction-Mount-Holder-for-Camera-GPS-iphone-4s-/160854779845?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2573b127c5

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?:

[image]

Comment: No. You know the images that you see in the top left corner of every eBay listing? You know how when you hover over the thumbnails, the large image changes? I want those larger images to stay intact and be viewable inside the PDF file.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure if you'll be able to do it.  Sorry!